How to use mitmproxy with Angular
I think I'm misunderstanding how this is suppose to work so I'd like some clarification:
I have an angular app with a proxy setup like so:
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}

For the proxy to work with angular I need to send my HTTP requests to angular itself running on the same port:
return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/api');

I want to use mitmproxy to intercept the requests and then forward them to a local Django server running on port 8000. But if I send the HTTP request to 8080 (mitmproxy's default port) by setting the target value it doesn't know how to forward the request and gets caught sending seemingly unlimited requests.
So what do I need to set (in the headers) to get the HTTP request to go through mitmproxy and on to the Django server?

You can extend mitmproxy by Python based scripts and e.g. redirect traffic to a different server: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/addons-examples/#http-redirect-requests

This sounds like you want to run mitmproxy in reverse proxy mode: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/. This makes it so that all requests are unconditionally forwarded to your Django app.
mitmproxy --mode reverse:http://localhost:8000

